# What is value of the question mark stands/standing for in the figure sequence given?

Tags: word-choice

> What is value of the question mark **stands** for in the figure sequence given?

I've seen this question in a book.
I don't understand why **"stands"** is used here instead of **"standing"**.

I think the question should have been either

> What does value of the question mark **stand** for in the figure sequence given?

or

> What is value of the question mark **standing** for in the figure sequence given?

Also, shouldn't **"the value"** have been better?

Comment: Can you add a source for the quotations? It would be helpful to understand if the problems are related to dialect, translation, or perhaps  typographical errors. Answers would become a matter of interpretation.

Comment: The sentence as you quote it is nonsensical. It looks like an editorial or typographical error; providing the name and author of the text would allow us to confirm whether that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is terrible.  If it was my book, I'd complain.

Amongst other errors, the writer can't decide which of these two things they are asking for:

- The value of the question mark
- The value that the question mark stands for

There are several ways to rephrase it to be grammatically correct.

Keeping the "What is...in the figure sequence given?" structure of the original sentence we could write:

> What is **the value of the question mark** in the figure sequence given?
>
> What is **the value that the question mark stands for** in the figure sequence given?

In this case you're correct that we need an article in front of the word 'value'.  Either question could be answered with:

> **The value** is seven.

There is another way to phrase this question though, using *the question mark* as the subject instead of *the value*, and your suggestions are close:

> "What value **does the question mark stand for** in the figure sequence
>   given?"
>
> "What value **is the question mark standing for** in the figure sequence
>   given?"

The word 'value' can be removed and they still make sense.

> "What **does the question mark stand for** in the figure sequence
>   given?"
>
> "What **is the question mark standing for** in the figure sequence
>   given?"

They could be answered with:

> **The question mark** stands for seven.
>
> **The question mark** is standing for seven.

The 'stands for' questions are more likely to be used in formal writing.  This looks like a question from a mathematics text book, so I would expect to see the more formal version.